# SpriteKit: unexpected physics issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I want a ball-sprite jump off the ground each time to the same height. But with every jump the maximum height position of the ball increases.

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
  if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

      SKNode *ground = [SKNode node];
      ground.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointZero toPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), 0)];
      [self addChild:ground];

      SKShapeNode *ball = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
      CGMutablePathRef myPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
      CGPathAddArc(myPath, NULL, 0, 0, 30, 0, M_PI*2, YES);
      ball.path = myPath;
      ball.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)-100);
      ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.frame.size.width/2];
      ball.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0;
      ball.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0;
      [self addChild:ball];

  }
  return self;
```

}

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at setting both the restitution and friction on both bodies, not just the ball. If it's growing and not shrinking though, there is likely an error with the physics bodies. `SKShapeNode` is notoriously unreliable in my testing - I would look into using `SKSpriteNode` instead to maintain your sanity.

Comment: what does the node have to do with the physics? Ie the underlying physics body is not affected by the view associated with it.

Comment: I thought the same thing, then started using circular shape nodes like OP and ran into strange issues with their physics bodies that were fixed by using sprite nodes. Maybe not the issue here, but either way I believe shape nodes will get you into trouble at some point in their current state. You disagree?

Comment: I find that highly unlikely. Why would the view make any difference to the body, body being the same? And why would the body be any different depending on the view? The only thing this can happen is if view properties like self.frame are used to initialize the physics body, like in this example (ie radius depends on ball.frame.size).

Comment: Replacing the SKShapeNode with an SKSpriteNode did effectively fix the issue. Ty!

Comment: Found out, that even if i use a `SKSpriteNode` it only works well with few images. Seems to be a problem with the physics bodies.

Comment: `SKShapeNode`s have been very unreliable in my testing as well. It's really a shame. They would have been great for prototyping etc. Physics just don't work with them.